# Rescale list of numbers

Tags: statistics

Suppose a survey asks people to determine their position on a topic by choosing a number among $0,1,2,...,10$, where $0$ denotes totally agreeing on the topic and $10$ denotes totally disagreeing on the topic.

After having received the responses, is there a formal way to "rescale" them between $0$ and $5$ so that they belong to the categories $0,1,2,3,4,5$ (i.e., only integers allowed)?

I would like something like "having answered $0$ in the scale $0-10$ is equivalent to having answer $X$ in the scale $0-5$", "having answered $1$ in the scale $0-10$ is equivalent to having answer $Y$ in the scale $0-5$", etc.

Comment: What's wrong with dividing by 2? Must $Y$ be an integer?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I have added that I want integers.